# How to convert Class Component into Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, mern

i am working only on class component but now i am trying function component. but i am not know much about the function component.
but after converting my class into function my code is not working well

Error:(in my functional component code) if i am click next button then it not show me 2nd question but after clicking again then it show me 2nd question.
then after im clicking the back button then it show me next question instead of previous question

But my Class component code is work properly.but after converted in functional component is not work correct. Means my converted functional component code is not correct.

Please help me in the converting class component into functional component.Or tell me what is incorrect in my converted functional component code.

...
...

Orignal Class Component

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";

import classnames from "classnames";
import isEmpty from "../is-empty";
import questionsArray from "../questions.json";

export default class PlayQuiz extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      questions: questionsArray,
      currentQuestion: {},
      nextQuestion: {},
      previousQuestion: {},
      answer: "",
      numberOfQuestions: 0,
      numberOfAnsweredQuestions: 0,
      currentQuestionIndex: 0,
      score: 0,
      correctAnswers: 0,
      wrongAnswers: 0,
      nextButtonDisabled: false,
      previousButtonDisabled: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      questions,
      currentQuestion,
      nextQuestion,
      previousQuestion,
    } = this.state;
    this.displayQuestions(
      questions,
      currentQuestion,
      nextQuestion,
      previousQuestion
    );
  }

  displayQuestions = (
    questions = this.state.questions,
    currentQuestion,
    nextQuestion,
    previousQuestion
  ) => {
    let { currentQuestionIndex } = this.state;
    if (!isEmpty(this.state.questions)) {
      questions = this.state.questions;
      currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex];
      nextQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex + 1];
      previousQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex - 1];
      const answer = currentQuestion.answer;
      this.setState(
        {
          currentQuestion: currentQuestion,
          nextQuestion,
          previousQuestion,
          numberOfQuestions: questions.length,
          answer,
        },
        () => {
          this.showOptions();
          this.handleDisableButton();
        }
      );
    }
  };

  handleOptionClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase() === this.state.answer.toLowerCase()) {
      console.log("correct");
      this.correctAnswer();
    } else {
      console.log("incorrect");
      this.wrongAnswer();
    }
  };

  correctAnswer = () => {
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => ({
        score: prevState.score + 1,
        correctAnswers: prevState.correctAnswers + 1,
        currentQuestionIndex: prevState.currentQuestionIndex + 1,
        numberOfAnsweredQuestions: prevState.numberOfAnsweredQuestions + 1,
      }),
      () => {
        if (this.state.nextQuestion === undefined) {
          this.endGame();
        } else {
          this.displayQuestions(
            this.state.questions,
            this.state.currentQuestion,
            this.state.nextQuestion,
            this.state.previousQuestion
          );
        }
      }
    );
  };

  wrongAnswer = () => {
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => ({
        wrongAnswers: prevState.wrongAnswer + 1,
        currentQuestionIndex: prevState.currentQuestionIndex + 1,
        numberOfAnsweredQuestions: prevState.numberOfAnsweredQuestions + 1,
      }),
      () => {
        if (this.state.nextQuestion === undefined) {
          this.endGame();
        } else {
          this.displayQuestions(
            this.state.questions,
            this.state.currentQuestion,
            this.state.nextQuestion,
            this.state.previousQuestion
          );
        }
      }
    );
  };

  showOptions = () => {
    const options = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".option"));

    options.forEach((option) => {
      option.style.visibility = "visible";
    });
  };

  handleNextButtonClick = () => {
    if (this.state.nextQuestion !== undefined) {
      this.setState(
        (prevState) => ({
          currentQuestionIndex: prevState.currentQuestionIndex + 1,
        }),
        () => {
          this.displayQuestions(
            this.state.question,
            this.state.currentQuestion,
            this.state.nextQuestion,
            this.state.previousQuestion
          );
        }
      );
    }
  };

  handlePreviousButtonClick = () => {
    if (this.state.previousQuestion !== undefined) {
      this.setState(
        (prevState) => ({
          currentQuestionIndex: prevState.currentQuestionIndex - 1,
        }),
        () => {
          this.displayQuestions(
            this.state.question,
            this.state.currentQuestion,
            this.state.nextQuestion,
            this.state.previousQuestion
          );
        }
      );
    }
  };

  handleQuitButtonClick = () => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure want to quite Quiz")) {
      //  this.props.history.push("/");
    }
  };
  handleButtonClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    switch (e.target.id) {
      case "next-button":
        this.handleNextButtonClick(e);
        break;

      case "previous-button":
        this.handlePreviousButtonClick(e);
        break;

      case "quit-button":
        this.handleQuitButtonClick(e);
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  handleDisableButton = () => {
    if (
      this.state.previousQuestion === undefined ||
      this.state.currentQuestionIndex === 0
    ) {
      this.setState({
        previousButtonDisabled: true,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        previousButtonDisabled: false,
      });
    }

    if (
      this.state.nextQuestion === undefined ||
      this.state.currentQuestionIndex + 1 === this.state.numberOfQuestions
    ) {
      this.setState({
        nextButtonDisabled: true,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        nextButtonDisabled: false,
      });
    }
  };
  endGame = () => {
    alert("Game has ended.");
    const { state } = this;
    const playerStats = {
      score: state.score,
      numberOfQuestions: state.numberOfQuestions,
      numberOfAnsweredQuestions: state.correctAnswers + state.wrongAnswers,
      correctAnswers: state.correctAnswers,
      wrongAnswers: state.wrongAnswers,
    };
    console.log(playerStats);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.history.push("/play/QuizSummary", playerStats);
    }, 1000);
  };

  render() {
    const {
      currentQuestion,
      currentQuestionIndex,
      numberOfQuestions,
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="questions">
          <h2>Quiz Mode</h2>
          <br />
          <h5>
            {currentQuestionIndex + 1}.{currentQuestion.question}
          </h5>
          <div className="options-container">
            <p onClick={this.handleOptionClick} className="option">
              {currentQuestion.opt1}
            </p>
            <p onClick={this.handleOptionClick} className="option">
              {currentQuestion.opt2}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="options-container">
            <p onClick={this.handleOptionClick} className="option">
              {currentQuestion.opt3}
            </p>
            <p onClick={this.handleOptionClick} className="option">
              {currentQuestion.opt4}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="button-container">
            <button
              className={classnames("", {
                disabled: this.state.nextButtonDisabled,
              })}
              id="previous-button"
              onClick={this.handleButtonClick}
            >
              Previous
            </button>
            <button
              className={classnames("", {
                disabled: this.state.nextButtonDisabled,
              })}
              id="next-button"
              onClick={this.handleButtonClick}
            >
              Next
            </button>
            <button id="quit-button" onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>
              Quit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

My Converted Functional Component

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import classnames from "classnames";
import isEmpty from "../is-empty";
import questionsArray from "../questions.json";

const PlayQuiz = ({withRouter}) => {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState(questionsArray);
  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState({
    content: "",
    question: "",
    opt1: "",
    opt2: "",
    opt3: "",
    opt4: "",
    answer: "",
  });
  const [nextQuestion, setNextQuestion] = useState({
    content: "",
    question: "",
    opt1: "",
    opt2: "",
    opt3: "",
    opt4: "",
    answer: "",
  });
  const [previousQuestion, setPreviousQuestion] = useState({
    content: "",
    question: "",
    opt1: "",
    opt2: "",
    opt3: "",
    opt4: "",
    answer: "",
  });
  const [numberOfQuestions, setNumberOfQuestions] = useState(0);
  const [numberOfAnsweredQuestions, setNumberOfAnsweredQuestions] = useState(0);
  const [currentQuestionIndex, setCurrentQuestionIndex] = useState(0);
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [correctAnswers, setCorrectAnswers] = useState(0);
  const [wrongAnswers, setWrongAnswers] = useState(0);
  const [nextButtonDisabled, toggleNextButtonDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [previousButtonDisabled, togglePreviousButtonDisabled] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    displayQuestion(questions, currentQuestion, nextQuestion, previousQuestion);
  }, []);

  const displayQuestion = (
    questions,
    currentQuestion,
    nextQuestion,
    previousQuestion
  ) => {
    if (!isEmpty(questions)) {
      // questions = questions;
      console.log("current Question Index:" + currentQuestionIndex);
      console.log("display");
      currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex];
      nextQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex + 1];
      previousQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex - 1];
      setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion);
      setNextQuestion(nextQuestion);
      setPreviousQuestion(previousQuestion);
      setNumberOfQuestions(questions.length);
      // showOption();
      handleDisableButton();
    }
  };

  const handleOptionClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (
      e.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase() === currentQuestion.answer.toLowerCase()
    ) {
      console.log("correct");
      correctAnswer();
    } else {
      console.log("incorrect");
      wrongAnswer();
    }
  };

  const correctAnswer = () => {
    setScore(score + 1);
    setCorrectAnswers(correctAnswers + 1);
    setCurrentQuestionIndex(currentQuestionIndex + 1);
    setNumberOfAnsweredQuestions(numberOfAnsweredQuestions + 1);

    if (nextQuestion === undefined) {
      endQuiz();
    } else {
      displayQuestion(
        questions,
        currentQuestion,
        nextQuestion,
        previousQuestion
      );
    }
  };

  const wrongAnswer = () => {
    setWrongAnswers(wrongAnswers + 1);
    setCurrentQuestionIndex(currentQuestionIndex + 1);
    setNumberOfAnsweredQuestions(numberOfAnsweredQuestions + 1);

    if (nextQuestion === undefined) {
      endQuiz();
    } else {
      displayQuestion(
        questions,
        currentQuestion,
        nextQuestion,
        previousQuestion
      );
    }
  };

  const handleNextButtonClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (nextQuestion !== undefined) {
      setCurrentQuestionIndex(currentQuestionIndex + 1);
      displayQuestion(
        questions,
        currentQuestion,
        nextQuestion,
        previousQuestion
      );
    }
  };

  const handlePreviousButtonClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (previousQuestion !== undefined) {
      setCurrentQuestionIndex(currentQuestionIndex - 1);
      displayQuestion(
        questions,
        currentQuestion,
        nextQuestion,
        previousQuestion
      );
    }
  };

 
  const handleQuitButtonClick = () => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure want to quite Quiz")) {
      //  this.props.history.push("/");
    }
  };
  const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    switch (e.target.id) {
      case "next-button":
        handleNextButtonClick(e);
        break;

      case "previous-button":
        handlePreviousButtonClick(e);
        break;

      case "quit-button":
        handleQuitButtonClick(e);
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  const handleDisableButton = () => {
    if (previousQuestion === undefined || currentQuestionIndex === 0) {
      togglePreviousButtonDisabled(true);
    } else {
      togglePreviousButtonDisabled(false);
    }

    if (
      nextQuestion === undefined ||
      currentQuestionIndex + 1 === numberOfQuestions
    ) {
      toggleNextButtonDisabled(true);
    } else {
      toggleNextButtonDisabled(false);
    }
  };
  const endQuiz = () => {
    alert("Quiz has ended.");
    const playerStats = {
      score: score,
      numberOfQuestions: numberOfQuestions,
      numberOfAnsweredQuestions: numberOfAnsweredQuestions,
      correctAnswers: correctAnswers,
      wrongAnswers: wrongAnswers,
    };
    console.log(playerStats);
    console.log(questionsData.questions);
    console.log(questionsArray);

    history.push("/give-exam/QuizSummary", playerStats);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="questions">
        <h2>Quiz Mode</h2>
        <br />
        <h5>
          {currentQuestionIndex + 1}.{currentQuestion.question}
        </h5>
        <div className="options-container">
          <p onClick={(e) => handleOptionClick(e)} className="option">
            {currentQuestion.opt1}
          </p>
          <p onClick={(e) => handleOptionClick(e)} className="option">
            {currentQuestion.opt2}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="options-container">
          <p onClick={(e) => handleOptionClick(e)} className="option">
            {currentQuestion.opt3}
          </p>
          <p onClick={(e) => handleOptionClick(e)} className="option">
            {currentQuestion.opt4}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="button-container">
          <button
            className={classnames("", { disabled: previousButtonDisabled })}
            id="previous-button"
            onClick={(e) => handleButtonClick(e)}
          >
            Previous
          </button>
          <button
            className={classnames("", { disabled: nextButtonDisabled })}
            id="next-button"
            onClick={(e) => handleButtonClick(e)}
          >
            Next
          </button>
          <button id="quit-button" onClick={(e) => handleButtonClick(e)}>
            Quit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};


export default withRouter(PlayQuiz);
```

questionArray.json

```
[
  {
    "question": "What temperature does water boil at?",
    "opt1": "50 degrees Celcius",
    "opt2": "25 degrees Celcius",
    "opt3": "100 degrees Celcius",
    "opt4": "150 degrees Celcius",
    "answer": "100 degrees Celcius"
  },

  {
    "question": "Who wrote Julius Caesar, Macbeth and Hamlet?",
    "opt1": "Wole Soyinka",
    "opt2": "William Shakespeare",
    "opt3": "Ngozi Chimamanda Adichie",
    "opt4": "Dan Brown",
    "answer": "William Shakespeare"
  },

  {
    "question": "What did the crocodile swallow in Peter Pan?",
    "opt1": "A Book",
    "opt2": "A Computer",
    "opt3": "A pair of shoes",
    "opt4": "Alarm Clock",
    "answer": "Alarm Clock"
  },

  {
    "question": "Which is the only mammal that can’t jump?",
    "opt1": "Dog",
    "opt2": "Elephant",
    "opt3": "Goat",
    "opt4": "Lion",
    "answer": "Elephant"
  },

  {
    "question": "Who lived at 221B, Baker Street, London?",
    "opt1": "Tony Stark",
    "opt2": "Morgan Freeman",
    "opt3": "Sherlock Holmes",
    "opt4": "Samuel L. Jackson",
    "answer": "Sherlock Holmes"
  },
]
```

isEmpty.js

```
const isEmpty = (value) =>
  value === undefined ||
  value === null ||
  (typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
  (typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length === 0);

export default isEmpty;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your class component in a Higher Order Component and turn it into a Functional Component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useHook } from '../hooks/useHook';

export const withFunctionalComponent = (Component) => {
  return (props) => {
    const hookValue = useHook();

    return <Component value={hookValue} {...props} />;
  };
};
```

And use it like so:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withFunctionalComponent } from './withFunctionalComponent';

class ClassComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello, {this.props.value}</div>;
  }
}

export default withFunctionalComponent (ClassComponent)
```